# Summing a column based on multiple data validation reference cells in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-chrome, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I need to be able to sum the total payout amount given that there are multiple entries for the same user. In addition, I have a dropdown data validation reference cell that should show a smaller total sum based on payout_amount.

For example, total sum is 1,270. But if I am just looking at payout_amount for loss_type = 'Theft', the sum is 750.

How would I do this in Google sheets? How would I do this for multiple criteria (multiple dropdown data validation)?

| user_id. | loss_type. | payout_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Theft | 500 |
| 2 | Theft | 250 |
| 3 | Liquid Damage | 180 |
| 3 | Liquid Damage | 180 |
| 4 | Liquid Damage | 225 |
| 4 | Cracked Screen | 225 |
| 4 | Cracked Screen | 225 |
| 5 | Battery Malfunction | 115 |
| 5 | Battery Malfunction | 115 |
| 5 | Battery Malfunction | 115 |

Answer (score 1):

`SUMIFS` and `UNIQUE` is highly effective for your case.

1. Create dropdown from all items of loss_type. Try formula `UNIQUE(B2:B)` on cell H2 to get the list of all loss_type.
2. Create dropdown on E2.
   Select E2 > Go to Data > Data Validation > Criteria (List from range) > Select `H2:H`
3. Then, use `SUMIFS` with the dropdown value as criteria on F2. Try the formula below -

   =SUMIFS(C:C, B:B, E2)

This should automatically provide you with a total sum payout, once you select your required value in E2.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need `SUMIFS()` function for multiple criteria. Try below formula-

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C11,B2:B11,D2)
```

You can add more criteria for more dropdown value like

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C11,B2:B11,D2,A2:A11,E2)
```

[image]

Comment: There are also some other formula you can utilize like `FILTER`, `QUERY`, `SUMPRODUCT` but `SUMIFS()` would be easier and best fit in your case.

Comment: I think the question was misphrased. Its more complicated. I want to sum for ALL users. I will not be filtering based on an ID.

Comment: Then use first formula. Do not add criteria for users. I have just shown how to use more criteria into formula. You can user just one criteria or many criteria as your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try QUERY.

```
=query(B1:C,"select B, sum(C) where B is not null group by B",1)
```

[image]

It's just one short formula and works for the whole range.